# Prisma Instance not finding model

Tags: prisma

I have a Next js App with a prisma instance creating the db from its schema. All models are callable with prisma.[any model]. The schema for the table I can not call is as following.

```
model ProjectTeam {
   id String @id @default(uuid())
   project String @db.VarChar()
   team String @db.VarChar()
}
```

I added this model as well as other models in the last migrations. But I can call those models in contrary to this one.

I call the model here:

```
wait Promise.all(assignedTeams.map(async (team) => {
   await prisma.projectTeam.create({
      data: {
         project: newProject.id,
            team: team,
      }
   })
}))
```

The error message when I try to create the project Team is:

```
app  | error - Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
```

I really can not see the problem here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify that the ProjectTeam table is created correctly after you generated the Prisma Client?

Comment: Hey Raphael, Thank you for the comment. Since this is a bit older, I should resolve the question. 

I found that the table was created correctly. But in combination with a older data instance, the model was not pushed to the database. So I could solve it with a npx prisma db push.